# track is fetched and playing but sound is not coming from speaker on IOS react-native-track-player

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-track-player

Describe the Bug

The track is successfully added into a queue and playing but after dragging multiple times like left or right the track shows it playing but the sound is not coming from the speaker when I press pause and then play everything works fine like the track is playing and sound is coming from the speaker.